# SQL Server Replication - Auto resolve conflicts

Tags: .net, sql-server, replication

I set merge replication up between two instances of SQL Server. Thus I have one publisher and one subscriber.

I read some articles about how to resolve conflicts and I have already used the interactive resolver which is a part of the SQL Server Management Studio.

However, I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to open the interactive resolver outside the Management Studio, i.e. from a .Net application?
2. I read that publisher and subscribers have different configurable priorities which are used to determine winners and loser during synchronization. But do I have to configure something else in order to "auto-resolve" conflicts based on these priorities?

Thanks